# Laravel route link with parameter not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

in my route have optional parameter. when I click my link then its create problem.It looks like

```
http://localhost/my/public/admin/category/sub-create?2
```

But it will be

```
http://localhost/my/public/admin/category/sub-create/2
```

My route

```
     Route::get('sub-create/{cid?}',['as'=>'new_sub_category',
'uses'=>'CategoryController@SubCategoryCreate']);
```

My link

```
<a href="{{route('new_sub_category', $categoryID)}}"
     class="btn bg-navy btn-flat margin">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add New Subcategory</a>
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using, I just replicated your route in tinker and didn't have any problems.

$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.6.1 (PHP 5.6.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Route::get('sub-create/{cid?}',['as'=>'new_sub_category',
... 'uses'=>'CategoryController@SubCategoryCreate']);
=> Illuminate\Routing\Route {#1026}
>>> route('new_sub_category', 2);
=> "http://localhost/sub-create/2"
>>>

Comment: version 5.2 @LoganBailey

Comment: Yeah, I can't duplicate this at all with a fresh laravel install. Maybe post your `php artisan route:list` or verify that `$categoryId` isn't wonky.

Comment: Can you verify that you're seeing the top result and you want the bottom result? Or do you want top result and you're seeing the bottom result?

Answer (score 2):

follow this way. This will create proper route

```
{{route('new_sub_category', ['cid'=>$categoryID])}}
```

---

```
<a href="{{route('new_sub_category', ['cid'=>$categoryID])}}"
     class="btn bg-navy btn-flat margin">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add New Subcategory</a>
```